# Perl floating point number usage confusion

Tags: perl

While using scalar values in perl, I am not able to accomplish the desired results. Need your help in figuring where I am going wrong..

Say I want to loop 9 times and print 0.1 to 0.9

I declared variable `$i` and using it in for loop as well as inside the loop.

```
for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) 
{
    $b = $ie-01; # (This where I go wrong, I am not sure If I am following correct
                 # syntax here, Because I see -1 getting printed instead of $i value
                 # which is incremented on each loop)
    print "The value now is: $b\n";
}
```

I do know of different ways to get the desired result but I wanna know how to use exponent to get the desired output. . . . .

Why `$i` is treated as `0` when used in conjunction with `e`?

Comment: You shouldn't use C-Style for loops in perl unless you have to use them. Try `for my $i (1..9) {` instead. Also, you should mark Howard's answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you only forgot to include the multiplication operator `*`:

```
$i * 1e-01
```

The string `$ie-01` will be interpreted as `$ie - 01` which is an unititialized variable (i.e. zero) minus one which will give you `-1`. (You can use the `e`-notation only with constant numbers but not with variables.)

Comment: Absolutely right .. I tried with the multiplication operator and it works !!! Thank you Howard.

Comment: One More Question though !! Why do I get an error when include a () ...like $i(e-01)

Because I knew I was doing something wrong there but I tried to bring in the braces to signify its different but I received errors on this line

Comment: @Jey Bela The multiplication operator `*` is not optional in perl. You also have to write `$i * (1e-01)`. As mentioned in my answer `e-01` only works with constant prefix.

Comment: If you had added the two lines `use strict;` `use warnings;` to the top of your script, Perl would have warned you that `$ie` was uninitialized.

Answer (score 6):

Your first mistake was not including:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

This would have told you about the variable `$ie` not being declared.

There is no reasonable way to make `${i}e-01` work; you would have to `eval` it, which is not reasonable.  The standard way to write it would be:

```
$b = $i * 0.1;
```